# Facebook marketing API not working with App token?

Tags: node.js, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-marketing-api, facebook-business-sdk

Facebook marketing API works fine with user access token in postman. But not working with app token? Is it possible to call Ad insights with app token?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

App Tokens do not have any relation to a user profile and the Marketing API is not public, so of course you cannot use an App Token. You have to authorize a user that is allowed to access the relevant data.

Comment: Is there any way to generate access token in Node? Most articles are creating access token via front end.

Comment: I read your answer for this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58421724/how-to-get-facebook-user-access-token-using-nodejs/58421900#58421900.

Thank you.