# How to get facebook user access token using NodeJS

Tags: node.js, facebook

How can I get a user access token using NodeJS ? I have tried mulitple approaches and I can't it to work using any of them

I tried [facebook-node-sdk](https://www.npmjs.com/package/fb) but, it seems it does require to have access-token beforehand.
I also tried [facebook-passport](https://github.com/passport/express-4.x-facebook-example) but I need to get that from backend to call Facebook APIs after that

**Edit**

am trying to do the login, and after that publishing posts automatically, I don't have a use who will approve on the facebook popup.

Comment: The process for accessing the Facebook API seems to be described [here](https://lorenstewart.me/2017/03/12/using-node-js-to-interact-with-facebooks-graph-api/) and [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps#register) and [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens/#usertokens).  I'm not sure what you're trying to do beyond what these describe.

Answer (score 1):

A simple approach:

- Use the JavaScript SDK: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/javascript/
- After getting a User Token with `FB.login`, transfer the Token to the server with AJAX and use it on the server - either with some SDK, or with axios/fetch/whatever.

Alternatively, you can build your own login flow: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/manually-build-a-login-flow/